# Добавление процентов и статуса загрузки внутрь ProgressBar

Tags: wpf

Имею `ListBox`, в котором есть `ProgressBar`. Как поместить `TextBox` с процентами и статусом во внутрь ProgressBar?

Пытался это сделать банальным помещением поверх, но словил ошибку:

> Свойство VisualTree установлено больше одного раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем не вижу, должно все работать:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar .../>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" .../>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ок, возможно я что-то делаю не так. Вот этот отрезок кода. [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/CvUr9QeG)

Comment: Оберните эти контролы в Grid, как у меня. В DataTemplate может быть только один корневой элемент

Comment: Ошибка пропала, а вот сам текстбокс так и не появился. UPD. Спасибо, вопрос закрыт.